# Layernorm in PyTorch

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, nlp, attention-model

Consider the following example:

```
    batch, sentence_length, embedding_dim = 2, 3, 4
    embedding = torch.randn(batch, sentence_length, embedding_dim)
    print(embedding)
    
# Output:
    tensor([[[-2.1918,  1.2574, -0.3838,  1.3870],
             [-0.4043,  1.2972, -1.7326,  0.4047],
             [ 0.4560,  0.6482,  1.0858,  2.2086]],
    
            [[-1.4964,  0.3722, -0.7766,  0.3062],
             [ 0.9812,  0.1709, -0.9177, -1.2558],
             [-1.1560, -0.0367,  0.5496, -1.1142]]])
```

Applying the Layernorm which normalized across the embedding dimension, I get:

```
layer_norm = torch.nn.LayerNorm(embedding_dim)
layer_norm(embedding)

# Output:
tensor([[[-1.5194,  0.8530, -0.2758,  0.9422],
         [-0.2653,  1.2620, -1.4576,  0.4609],
         [-0.9470, -0.6641, -0.0204,  1.6315]],

        [[-1.4058,  0.9872, -0.4840,  0.9026],
         [ 1.3933,  0.4803, -0.7463, -1.1273],
         [-0.9869,  0.5545,  1.3619, -0.9294]]],
       grad_fn=<NativeLayerNormBackward0>)
```

Now, when I normalize the first vector of above embedding tensor with a naive python implementation, I get:

```
    a = [-2.1918,  1.2574, -0.3838,  1.3870]
    mean_a = statistics.mean(a)
    var_a = statistics.stdev(a)
    eps = 1e-5
    d = [ ((i-mean_a)/math.sqrt(var_a + eps)) for i in a]
    print(d)
    
    #Output:
[-1.7048934056508998,0.9571791768620398,-0.3094894774404756,1.0572037062293356]
```

The normalized values are not the same as what I get from PyTorch's Layernorm. Is there something wrong with the way I calculated Layernorm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is the variance not the standard deviation (the standard deviation is the sqrt of the variance, and you're getting the sqrt in your calculation of `d`).
Also, this uses the biased variance (statistics.pvariance). To reproduce the expected results using the statistics module you'll use:

```
a = [-2.1918,  1.2574, -0.3838,  1.3870]
mean_a = statistics.mean(a)
var_a = statistics.pvariance(a)
eps = 1e-5
d = [ ((i-mean_a)/math.sqrt(var_a + eps)) for i in a]
print(d)
[-1.519391435327454, 0.8530327107709863, -0.2758152854532861, 0.942174010009754]
```

Another way to verify correct results is:

```
[[torch.mean(i).item(), torch.var(i, unbiased=False).item()] for i in layer_norm(embedding)]

[[1.9868215517249155e-08, 0.9999885559082031],
[-1.9868215517249155e-08, 0.9999839663505554]]
```

This shows that the mean and variance of the normalized embeddings are (very close to) 0 and 1, as expected.

relevant [doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LayerNorm.html):
"The standard-deviation is calculated via the biased estimator, equivalent to torch.var(input, unbiased=False)."

Comment: Thanks. I didn't change the formula for variance. Is there any particular reason to use biased variance for this?

Comment: I suspect that the idea here is that since you're trying to normalize the values given, the data being normalized is the whole "population" not just a sample.